# How add not imported image to output build with vite?

Tags: vite

I have an `app` folder with some images that are used by the external script and I need to include those images in the dist build folder.

I tried to log files that go to output and those images are not included. I tried to add `assetsInclude` property but seems that property is not for that purpose.

How can I include some specific images in `dist` folder that aren't imported explicitly ?
Here is my `vite.config.js` file.

```js
import { resolve, parse } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  root: resolve(__dirname, 'app'),

  assetsInclude: ['/app/images/externalImage.png'],

  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        dir: './dist',
        assetFileNames: (asset) => {
          console.log(parse(asset.name).name);
          if (parse(asset.name).name === 'externalImage') {
            return "images/src/[name][extname]";
          }
          return "assets/[name].[hash][extname]";
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my js file which is included as a module inside the HTML file, I added string that you can see below. [Here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) is details of how to expose the current module URL.

`app/js/app.js`

```js
new URL("../images/src/externalImage.png", import.meta.url);
```

Also changed a bit config - added `outDir` prop:

```js
import { resolve, parse } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  root: resolve(__dirname, 'app'),

  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    emptyOutDir: true,
    
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (asset) => {
          if (parse(asset.name).name === 'externalImage') {
            return "images/src/[name][extname]";
          }
          return "assets/[name].[hash][extname]";
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) you can
place the asset in a special `public` directory under your project root. Assets in this directory will be served at root path `/` during dev, and copied to the root of the dist directory as-is.

The directory defaults to `<root>/public`, but can be configured via the `publicDir` option.

**Note that:**

- You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, `public/icon.png` should be referenced in source code as `/icon.png`.
- Assets in `public` cannot be imported from JavaScript.